deep-link to Google TV and Android TV and Android TV network settings
Developing the Android TV app, I need to deep-link to Google TV and Android TV and Android TV BOX AND ANDROID PHONE network settings screen to help users configure the network quickly. any solutions?
ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS and ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS are two commonly used actions for network configurations.

Deep-linking to network settings across different Android platforms (Google TV, Android TV, Android TV Box, and Android phones) requires using platform-independent intents to ensure compatibility. Android provides an action to open network settings:
ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS and ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS are two commonly used actions for network configurations.
Here’s how you can implement this functionality in a way that works for all mentioned Android platforms:
Complete Code
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class NetworkSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_network_settings)

        val btnOpenNetworkSettings: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenNetworkSettings)

        btnOpenNetworkSettings.setOnClickListener {
            openNetworkSettings()
        }
    }

    private fun openNetworkSettings() {
        try {
            // Create an intent to open network settings
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

            // Check if the intent can be resolved
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                // Fallback to generic wireless settings
                val fallbackIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
                fallbackIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

                if (fallbackIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    startActivity(fallbackIntent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Unable to open network settings on this device.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error opening settings: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

Key Points:

Primary Intent:

Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS opens the Wi-Fi settings directly.


Fallback Intent:

Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS opens a more generic wireless settings screen in case Wi-Fi settings are unavailable or unsupported.


Error Handling:

Displays a Toast if neither intent resolves or an exception occurs.



UI Layout (activity_network_settings.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpenNetworkSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open Network Settings"
        android:padding="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>

Explanation:

Cross-Device Compatibility: Using intents such as ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS and ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS ensures compatibility with different Android platforms.
Fallback Logic: Includes a fallback for cases where the primary intent is unavailable on the device.
Error Handling: Catches exceptions and shows a helpful message to the user if the action fails.

